# retrieve memory location in assembly

Tags: assembly, x86

My problem is I have to write a program that calls malloc using assembly language. However I do not know how to retrieve the address of the area allocated. Will it store it in memory somewhere, and if so, how to I find it?

Comment: return values are usually stored in `%eax` on i386, `%rax` on x86_64, and `r0` on ARM. Usually then, it is in the first register, but the answer is architecture-dependent, as Greg has pointed out.

Comment: I'm using intel 32bit. I think i'm using NASM.

Answer (score 2):

The simplest solution is to write a trivial C program that calls malloc and does something you can easily trace with the result (such as storing it in an external variable), compile it, and then look at the generated assembly code.

For example:

```
extern void * somePointer;
extern int someInt;
void callMalloc(void) 
{
     somePointer = malloc(someInt);
}
```

Compiling this on Linux, x86_64 gives:

```
    movslq  someInt(%rip), %rdi
    call    malloc
    movq    %rax, somePointer(%rip)
```

So that's exactly what you need to do -- put the number of bytes in `%rdi`, call `malloc`, and copy the result from `%rax`.

Answer (score 0):

If you're doing Win32, it looks like it returns it in EAX (grabbed some old code I wrote a couple years ago and that's what it looks like the macro returns it in).

Answer (score 0):

`malloc` is a C library function, and all C functions adhere to what's known as a [calling convention](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_calling_conventions). This describes how arguments are passed in, and how the result is returned.

If you're calling C functions from assembly, you should really know what calling convention is used for the C code.

Different compilers/libraries have different calling conventions, but the most common all return integer/pointer values in the `eax` register on x86 (at least true for `cdecl` on Linux/gcc and `syscall` for the Windows API).

Here's an example of calling `malloc` using `cdecl`:

```
push 24       ; Push the number of bytes we want to allocate    
call _malloc  ; Call malloc
add esp, 4    ; Undo the push

mov dword ptr [eax], 10   ; Set the first dword of the block to 10
mov dword ptr [eax+4], 5  ; Set the second dword of the block to 5
```